# How can I get the CodeClimate CLI to emit more detail?

Tags: code-climate, code-climate-cli

I'm using the [CodeClimate CLI](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate) to perform analysis of a codebase I've inherited, and, while it certainly works, its output is quite limited.

For example, when it says

```
23-30: Similar code found in 4 other locations (mass = 27) [duplication]
```

It would be nice if it said which 4 other locations, and showed a small code snippet.

Is there a way to get more verbose output?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably hoping for more information in the text output; I don't think there's any way to get that in the stock Code Climate CLI.

The best I know how to do is to look at the JSON output, which you get by running `codeclimate` with the `json` format:

```
codeclimate analyze -f json
```

(or e.g. `codeclimate analyze -e duplication -f json` to give yourself less JSON to wade through). Code Climate uses JSON internally and [the JSON formatter](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate/blob/master/lib/cc/analyzer/formatters/json_formatter.rb) just passes it through, so every piece of information that an engine emits is there.

If you want richer text output, you'd have to extend `codeclimate` yourself. You'd need to modify [the plain text formatter](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate/blob/master/lib/cc/analyzer/formatters/plain_text_formatter.rb) to understand the additional JSON that the engine you're interested in emits.